# In Java, how to find a string from an string array and why is the below example not working as expected

Tags: java

how to find a string from an string array and In the below example i am always get search failure except search for first string but not others like second or third , i even tried with [indexof !=1 condition  instead of equals ] but it remains same result  and why ? - please advise . Thanks

My Example :

```
String[] TEXT_ARRAY = {"first","second","third" };
    String parameter ="second";

    for (String string : TEXT_ARRAY) {
    System.out.println("****** [containsScript ? ]  IS EQUALS ?  " + parameter.toString().toUpperCase().equals(string.toString().toUpperCase()));
    }
```

Comment: string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2) is a more succinct way of checking equality ignoring case.

Comment: this is working,what are expecting?and what are  you getting?

Comment: OP has put incorrect code into the question which is why the exercise works. See the second comment on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9291905/977087) answer to see OPs actual problematic code

Answer (score 1):

Your script works as expected, printing:

[containsScript ? ]  IS EQUALS ?  false

[containsScript ? ]  IS EQUALS ?  true

[containsScript ? ]  IS EQUALS ?  false

You have lots of redundant code though, your condition could be rewritten as:

```
System.out.println("****** [containsScript ? ]  IS EQUALS ?  " + parameter.equalsIgnoreCase(string));
```

Also, what exactly do you need to achieve? If you want to test if a given String exists in a set of Strings, then I would advise using a Set, instead of an array and iterating over it every time you need to do that check.

Comment: you are correct the actual example posted in above works fine but by mistake i posted a wrong example , please try below where trying to find string other than first one like "onabort"  fails - please suggest ?

Comment: you are correct pcalcao , the actual example posted in above works fine but by mistake i posted a wrong example , please try below where trying to find string other than first one like "onabort" fails - please suggest ?  Example  String[] TEXT2 = {"document.write", " onabort", " onactivate", " onafterprint"};

  
       // String parameter2 ="document.write";
  String parameter2 ="onabort";
                
  for (String string : TEXT2) {
  System.out.println("****** [containsScript ? ]  IS EQUALS ?  " + parameter2.equalsIgnoreCase(string));
  }

Comment: Please update your question to reflect your problem as clearly as possible. I think your mistake is that you're setting the variable "parameter2" twice, to different values. When inside the cycle, only the last of these values still holds, the first is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me. The result will be

```
false
true
false
```

Note: I think toString() method is not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help you. I wrote this method for searching user's name in the string array.

```
public static void poisk(String serchingname, String... names) {

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        boolean notfound = false;
        if (serchingname.equals(names[i])) {
            System.out.println("User with name " + serchingname + " is found");
            break;
        }
        while (i==names.length-1) {
            if (serchingname.equals(names[names.length - 1]) == notfound) {
                System.out.println("User with name  " + serchingname + " is not found");
                break;
```

Answer (score -1):

Strings are actually immutable. If you have two strings that have the same content then they will be the same Object due to [String interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

So you should be able to do:

`parameter.equals(string)`

For your search, if it makes it easier you could do:

`Arrays.asList(TEXT_ARRAY).contains(parameter)`

That would work exactly the same as your loop.

Comment: `"If you have two strings that have the same content then they will be the same Object"` This is true only for String literals. If that was true we could use `operator==` to check strings equality. Also, your suggestion fails if one want to concider `"a"` and `"A"` as identicals.

Comment: They are String literals in the example.

Answer (score -1):

Change the System.out to

System.out.println("****** [containsScript ? ]  IS EQUALS ?  " +( parameter.toString().toUpperCase().equals(string.toString().toUpperCase())));

Comment: Please remove the redundant `toString()` and `toUpperCase()` methods.

Comment: @Jivings: the `toUpperCase()` is not redundant, if one want to concider `"a"` and `"A"` as identical strings.

Comment: Use `equalsIgnoreCase()` then.